# Reward user with item after leaving a review

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

In my app, I have a "rate us" button and I want to make it so that the user receives a hefty reward if he/she leaves a review on my game.

But I don't want the user to be able to press the button, then immediately go back into the app and get the reward without leaving a review.

How would I set that up?

Here is my code I'm using to redirect the user to my review section of the app:

```
let appID = "1292341923"
let reviewString = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id\(appID)?ls=1&mt=8&action=write-review"

func open(url: URL) {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
         UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
             print("Open \(url): \(success)")
         })
     } else if UIApplication.shared.openURL(url) {
            print("Open \(url): succeeded")
     }
}

if let checkURL = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=\(appID)&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=2&type=Purple+Software&mt=8") {
    open(url: checkURL)
} else {
    print("invalid url")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting a review send is **not possible**. Due to the application sandbox, you **cannot directly detect** the user's behaviour in another app if the action is not documented, especially not in a system app.

The closest thing you can do is, indeed, redirecting the user to the App Store's review page.